# how to select and drag objects in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URWru/) as an example here i used fabric.js in this will create lines when we button clicked .. my problem is how to select or move objects in the canvas in fabric.js ?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var line, isDown;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.add(line);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```

if i make the first line as `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: true });` i can get the bounding box but i can"t able to drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var line, isDown;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
    if(canvas.findTarget(o.e))return;
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ pointer.x, pointer.y, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.add(line);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  line.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```